# Creating and finding dynamic controls on a page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, winforms

There is a problem to find a dynamic control on a page. The dynamic control is created every time when a user press a button. The button calls the following JavaScript function and create a new components.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uploadCount = 1;
    function addFileInput(fName) {
        var only_file_name = fName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        var $div = $('<div />', {runat: 'server'});
        var $cbox = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'attachement' + uploadCount, value: fName, checked: "true", runat: 'server'}).addClass;
        var $label = $('<label />', { 'for': 'attachement' + uploadCount, text: only_file_name });
        $div.append($cbox);            
        $div.append($label);
        $('#newAttachment').append($div);
        $("#uploadCountValue").prop("value", uploadCount);
        uploadCount++;            
    }
</script>
```

## newAttachment is DIV section on the page.

```
<div id="newAttachement" runat="server" />
```

The DIV section is situated inside  section. The problem is when a user presses the button on the form I can't find the dynamic created components. The following code shows how I try to find the components:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(uploadCountValue.Value); i++)
            {
                if (RecursiveFind(newAttachement, "attachement" + i) != null)
                {
                    ... to do something
                }
}

public Control RecursiveFind(Control ParentCntl, string NameToSearch)
{
    if (ParentCntl.ID == NameToSearch)
       return ParentCntl;

    foreach (Control ChildCntl in ParentCntl.Controls)
            {
                Control ResultCntl = RecursiveFind(ChildCntl, NameToSearch);
                if (ResultCntl != null)
                    return ResultCntl;
            }
            return null;
}
```

I have detected that Controls count value is always zero in spite of there are dynamic components there.
I would be happy to get any help from us. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to find the controls created in the client-end you can't search them in the Page.Controls collection instead try to look for them in the Request.Form[] array

Answer (score 0):

you are creating the dynamic controls in javascript? i.e. you are creating html elements in javascript. It won't matter even if you put a runat="server" attribute in there, because it is still at the client-end. That would not be a part of the viewstate bag, so not populated in the controls collection.

you need to change your logic. create dynamic control in code-behind on button postback.

Comment: create dynamic control in code-behind on button postback. Could you show me simple example please?

Comment: >you need to change your logic. create dynamic control in code-behind on button postback. It should be like gmail when attach the files to a new letter. Probably gmail uses ajax withour reloading the page.

Comment: In that case, you do not need to search for controls in code-behind. You extract values in Javascript and then use AJAX to post those values to your webmethod.

Comment: `function addFileInput(fName) {
....
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Add.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
                data: '{name: "' + fName + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
}`

Comment: If you look at the code above you can see i use fName value from the head params of the function. In this case the code does not work properly. If i use a constant or declare another variable inside the function, it work ok. Could you explain me why I can not use the value from the head of the function in ajax section?

Comment: put an alert just after the function declaration: `function addFileInput(fName) { alert(fName); }`. Is the parameter being passed properly?

Comment: The value is set properly. The problem is that I try to POST a path of a file on my PC. I tried to use ('') to select the string dut it does not solve the problem. May be you can give me some advices?

Comment: hm, can you check the following lines on you pc because it seems work very strange. just declare variable like var s = "C:\fakepath\public_4556310_1b_bfc8e5d81170.jpg"; alert(s); my browser shows without slashes. does it work properly?

Comment: indeed \f and \p are like \n